# Arguments for make

Tags: command-line, make, makefile

I know you can pass arguments like parameters, for example, `make foo=bar`. I am wondering if I can do this with only one argument, without the variable. For example, this is what I would like to do:

```
hello:
    echo "Hello, $1!"
```

In Bash, $1 is the first argument passed through a function. If I ran `make hello 'world'`, then it should output `Hello, world!`. Is this possible?

Comment: You're attempting to misuse Make.  The positional arguments denote recipes to invoke/ targets to build.  You can perform some nasty hacks to coerce Make to do what you're asking (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run), but you would do much better to use Make as it was intended and pass `Message="Dont abuse Make"` from the command line

Comment: also, don't confuse `make` and `Makefile`s with Bash scripts - they're completely different and as such makefiles are NOT designed to be used like Bash scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fully agree with DWD and Thomas. But if, for any reason, you are forced to use `make` and a `Makefile`, please remember that `make` will consider all the arguments which are neither definitions nor execution flags as targets. It will attempt to update all of them in sequence, one at a time. So:

```
make hello VAR=value how are -d you --debug=n
```

Will consider `-d` and `--debug=n` as execution flags (or options) and `VAR=value` a definition of variable `VAR`. All other arguments will be treated as targets.

If you are using GNU `make`, you can benefit from certain special variables, such as `MAKECMDGOALS` which contains a complete list of targets to be updated. With the assistance of functions such as `firstword`, `wordlist` and `words`, we can isolate the first target from the rest:

```
# Takes the first target as command
Command := $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))
# Skips the first word
Arguments := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

The rule for `hello` is pretty simple:

```
hello:
    @echo "Hello, "$(Arguments)"!";
```

If you run `make hello 'world'`, you will get what you expect, but make will also attempt to build `world` as a target, and so with any other strings that you pass after hello.

The solution will come with the last resource rule: `%::`. It will be evaluated when no other rule can be applied. To stay quiet (no output, no errors) the recipe could be `@true`:

```
%::
    @true
```

Wrapping up everything, the final `Makefile` would look like:

```
Command := $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))
Arguments := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

hello:
    @echo "Hello, "$(Arguments)"!";

%::
    @true
```

This has many limitations. The first one is that if you extend the repertoire beyond a simple `hello`, those new targets will be evaluated in addition to being echoed by `hello`. Another limitation has to do with the invalid command handling. You will have to use the `filter` function to determine if the target is the first one in the line (actual command) or an argument to the command.